# Know when song is done playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

In my app I have a few buttons that play songs when pressed.  When a song is done, I want to change the image on the play/stop button to the play image.  I know I could set a timer to check to make sure the right image is displayed, but I feel like this would be a waste of system resources.  Is there a way to know when a song is done playing or something else? (Also, I'm using the AVAudioPlayer)
-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a delegate, and respond to the [`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate) callback.

Comment: How do you set up a delegate?

Comment: @LaurenG: There's an excellent explanation in the [docs, under "Delegates and Data Sources"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18). Basically, you would set `audioPlayer.delegate = self;` and implement the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` method in your class. This is a very common technique for interacting with other objects in Objective-C, you'll encounter it over and over again.

Comment: @interface player : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>